# Clear all code blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

Say you have an org file with **several** code blocks like the one below:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC jupyter-python :session py :results silent :async yes
stuff
more stuff
even more stuff
#+END_SRC
```

Question: Is there any function that would clear the contents of all code blocks, while leaving the code block declaration in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know whether there is an existing function to clear all org source blocks, but here is a quick example of how to do it.

CAVEAT:  This example does not check for broken source code blocks; e.g., the code assumes there is a matching beginning/ending.

```lisp
(defun org-clear-src-blocks ()
"Clear src code blocks."
(interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while (re-search-backward "#\\+END_SRC" nil t)
      (let ((reg-end (point))
            reg-beg)
        (re-search-backward "#\\+BEGIN_SRC" nil t)
        (setq reg-beg (1+ (line-end-position)))
        (delete-region reg-beg reg-end)))))
```

Comment: Works very well! Thanks for sharing! :D

Answer (score 4):

I use code like this to do that.

```
(defun scimax-ob-clear-all-contents ()
  "Clear all src-block contents in the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (org-babel-next-src-block)
      (org-edit-special)
      (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
      (org-edit-src-exit))))
```

If you just want to remove all the results, I use this.

```
(defun scimax-ob-clear-all-results ()
  "Clear all results in the buffer."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (org-babel-next-src-block)
      (org-babel-remove-result))))
```

Comment: Your code looks very neat! I'm sorry if I am confused but I think your code is removing the `results` part of the code block, while I was looking for something to remove the contents (the code) inside the code block.

Comment: Indeed, I misread the first question! I updated my answer with a similar approach to remove the contents.

Comment: Thanks for the update, the code reads well!

Comment: @JohnKitchin: That was a very sensible misreading! I've often wanted to clear all results but never have I wanted to clear all code blocks. Maybe it's the [Ikea effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKEA_effect)? Maybe I feel more attached to the code I wrote than to the results the computer calculated?